# Optimizing an expression – find identical subexpressions and substitute them

Tags: simplifying-expressions, code-generation

I'd like to simplify a complex symbolic expression `expr` by substituting and listing subexpressions that appear more than once in `expr` – kind of like Matlab does.

I need to port the result to C code, so the motivation is avoiding unnecessary recomputation of subterms.

To illustrate the idea, let's pick a simple expression `expr = Inverse[Array[a, {2,2}]]`:

**Actual output of MMA when executing `Inverse[Array[a, {3,3}]]`**:

$$
    \left(
    \begin{array}{cc}
     \frac{a(2,2)}{a(1,1) a(2,2)-a(1,2) a(2,1)} & -\frac{a(1,2)}{a(1,1)     a(2,2)-a(1,2) a(2,1)} \\
     -\frac{a(2,1)}{a(1,1) a(2,2)-a(1,2) a(2,1)} & \frac{a(1,1)}{a(1,1)     a(2,2)-a(1,2) a(2,1)} \\
    \end{array}
    \right)
$$

By looking at the output of this simple expression, I can see that the denominator is exactly the same in all of the matrix's elements (the determinant of the matrix).

**The desired output of MMA:**
$$
    \left(
    \begin{array}{cc}
     \frac{a(2,2)}{S_1} & -\frac{a(1,2)}{S_1} \\
     -\frac{a(2,1)}{S_1} & \frac{a(1,1)}{S_1} \\
    \end{array}
    \right),
$$

Where:

$$S_1 = a(1,1) a(2,2)-a(1,2) a(2,1)$$

Comment: `Inverse[Array[a, {2, 2}]] /. {-a[1, 2] a[2, 1] + a[1, 1] a[2, 2] -> 
   S1}`

Comment: Have a look at ``Experimental`OptimizeExpression[Inverse[Array[a, {2, 2}]]]``.

Comment: @corey979 I forgot to mention that I don't know what subexpressions are duplicated in `expr` (in my case `expr` is composed of operations on 6x6 matrices).

Comment: @J.M. Thank you. This seems like what I had in mind. Please consider posting this as an answer – I'll accept it. P.S. Am I right that there's no documentation for ``Experimental`OptimizeExpression``?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I noted in my comment above, the ***undocumented*** (thus, *caveat emptor* as usual) method is to use `` Experimental`OptimizeExpression[] ``:

```
Experimental`OptimizeExpression[Inverse[Array[a, {2, 2}]]]
   Experimental`OptimizedExpression[
       Block[{Compile`$9, Compile`$10, Compile`$11, Compile`$12, Compile`$14,
              Compile`$15, Compile`$16, Compile`$17}, 
             Compile`$9 = a[2, 2]; Compile`$10 = a[1, 2]; Compile`$11 = a[2, 1]; 
             Compile`$12 = -Compile`$10 Compile`$11; Compile`$14 = a[1, 1]; 
             Compile`$15 = Compile`$14 Compile`$9; 
             Compile`$16 = Compile`$12 + Compile`$15; 
             Compile`$17 = 1/Compile`$16;
             {{Compile`$9 Compile`$17, -Compile`$10 Compile`$17},
              {-Compile`$11 Compile`$17, Compile`$14 Compile`$17}}]]
```

The output has a slightly messy appearance, but if you take a careful look at the output, you'll see that e.g. the common factor in the elements of the matrix inverse (i.e. the reciprocal of the determinant) has been separated out, in this case as `` Compile`$17 ``.